# Software watchdog timer in Windows

Tags: c, windows, timer, watchdog

I'd like to create a simple watchdog timer in Windows, which will invoke a callback if certain time elapses since the last timer reset.

I thought of using a [timer queue timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003(v=vs.85).aspx), but it seems that I need to call `DeleteTimerQueueTimer` each time I want to "postpone" the timer:

```
// This is called whenever data is received from a device.
// If not called within a certain period, timerCallbackFn will
// be invoked on a separate thread.
void resetWatchdog(void)
{
    if (_timer->handle != NULL)
    {
        // cancel previous timer
        DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, (HANDLE)_timer->handle, NULL);
        _timer->handle = NULL;
    }

    // create new "one shot" timer
    CreateTimerQueueTimer(&_timer->handle,
        NULL,
        timerCallbackFn,
        _timer,
        _timer->intervalMs,   // fire once, after the specified interval
        0,                    // not periodic
        0);
}
```

Is this the correct approach? Do I need to use delete/create each time? Or is this the wrong timer for the job altogether?

Comment: Update the timer periodicity via ChangeTimerQueueTimer rather than deleting & recreating?

Comment: @AlexK.: Crap I can't believe I didn't see that one. Perhaps i misread "Change" as "Create". Please post this as the answer.

Comment: I didn't realise it was a one shot, you can't update an expired non-periodic q timer.

Comment: I don't need to update it after it has expired, I need to reset it periodically from my code, to *prevent* it from firing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k) [`ChangeTimerQueueTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-changetimerqueuetimer) is the way to update an existing timer-queue timer that was created by [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-createtimerqueuetimer).

Comment: Since comments are transient, I lifted the answer-in-comment to a proper answer. Marked as community wiki since it isn't my answer.